# c# Instantiate a class by setting a member value

Tags: c#

Currently when setting a member variable of on object I check if the object is instantiated. Is this really necessary, or is the object instantiated by just setting one member variable?

```
Person _Person;      

public int Age
{
  get
  {
    return _Person.Age;
  }
  set
  {
    if (_Person != null)
      _Person.Age = value;
    else
      _Person = new _Person(value);
  }
}
```

Is that the same as below?

```
Person _Person;      

public int Age
{
  get
  {
    return _Person.Age;
  }
  set
  {
    _Person.Age = value;
  }
}
```

Comment: Inside your class you have a reference to an instance of another class (`Person`), properties of which you expose as properties of your object? Then yes, you should instantiate `_Person` first, but I believe you either want to do that in the constructor or look at inheritance.

Comment: Why dont you try it ?

Comment: Your current handling would also throw a NullReferenceException when you would get the Age before setting it -> you should either do the null check in the getter as well, or eagerly instantiate the Person which would mean that you no longer need to do the null checks

Comment: This class is a launch class that is called by a framework, the properties are actualy settings which are passed by the launch class to the object that is show in the framework

Comment: @ kyle; because it worked, but I did not trust it. Apparently somewhere this class is called without me knowing it

Comment: As as side note: This line doesn't work as expected: `_Person.Age = Age;`. It simply sets `_Person.Age` to `Age`, which returns `_Person.Age`, so basically you're saying `_Person.Age = _Person.Age`. What you want is `_Person.Age = value;`.

Comment: @  Icepickle; that is a good point, I need to check that, all these variables are called in the Framework in a real strange order, so better safe than sorry

Comment: @ Thorsten Dittmar: You're right, changed that in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you must instantiate to allocate the memory in the variable.  With out instantiating the variable will be always equal to `null`

> When an instance constructor has no constructor initializer, or it has
>   a constructor initializer of the form base(...), that constructor
>   implicitly performs the initializations specified by the
>   variable-initializers of the instance fields declared in its class.
>   This corresponds to a sequence of assignments that are executed
>   immediately upon entry to the constructor and before the implicit
>   invocation of the direct base class constructor.